# How display Average Ratings on several pages in Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-templates, rating

Am trying to display the **Average ratings on other pages in Django, but it fails**. Below its my code.

**models.py**

```
class ActionGame(models.Model):
    
    publication_status = models.CharField(max_length=20, choices=STATUS, default="Draft")
    cid =ShortUUIDField(help_text='Place for the Game ID ', unique=True, max_length=10, length=7, prefix='act',alphabet='abcdfgh12345' )
    game_name = models.CharField(max_length=50, help_text='Enter The Name Of Game')
    game_image = models.ImageField(help_text='Enter The Game Picture Here',default='Action-images/default.jpg',upload_to='Action-images')

RATING=[
    (1,"★"),
    (2,"★★"),
    (3,"★★★"),
    (4,"★★★★"),
    (5,"★★★★★"),
]
class ActionGameReview(models.Model):
    game_name =models.ForeignKey(ActionGame, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='reviews')
    user =models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    review =models.TextField(max_length=5000, blank=False)
    rating = models.IntegerField(default=1, choices=RATING)
    created_at=models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

**Views.py**

```
def action_description(request, cid):
    description=ActionGame.objects.get(cid=cid)
    #getting Average Review
    avg_rating=ActionGameReview.objects.filter(game_name=ActionGame.objects.get(cid=cid)).aggregate(rating=Avg('rating'))
    # ......


def action(request):
    action_pages = ActionGame.published.all()
    # .....
```

This is my template for **Action View**

```
  {% for action_game in action_games %}
  
  <div class="col-md-6 themed-grid-col title-4-1 mt-5">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-7 themed-grid-col title-4-1-1  "> <img src="{{action_game.game_image.url }}" alt="" srcset=""></div>
      <div class="col-md-5 themed-grid-col title-4-1-2 ">
        <a href="{{ action_game.get_absolute_url }}"><b>{{ action_game.game_name }}</b></a> <br>
        <a href="https://{{action_game.official_site}}"><strong class="dev">{{action_game.developer}}</strong> </a><br>

<!----===== this is section for the Average Ratings of each game====---->
       
        <b>{{ action_rating }}</b> <br>
<!--===========================================================-->

        <p>
          <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-download" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
            <path d="M.5 9.9a.5.5 0 0 1 .5.5v2.5a1 1 0 0 0 1 1h12a1 1 0 0 0 1-1v-2.5a.5.5 0 0 1 1 0v2.5a2 2 0 0 1-2 2H2a2 2 0 0 1-2-2v-2.5a.5.5 0 0 1 .5-.5z"/>
            <path d="M7.646 11.854a.5.5 0 0 0 .708 0l3-3a.5.5 0 0 0-.708-.708L8.5 10.293V1.5a.5.5 0 0 0-1 0v8.793L5.354 8.146a.5.5 0 1 0-.708.708l3 3z"/>
          </svg>
          &nbsp; 250.4K
        </p>  
        <a href="{{ action_game.get_absolute_url }}"><button class="btn btn-outline-success">Download</button></a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
 
  {% endfor %}
```

The issue is, l cant display the ratings average in the **action view template** yet on the *action-description Works veryfine.*

how can l imprement the Average Rating on other pages, Anyone to help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `annotate` to count a rating for each `ActionGame` object:

```py
from django.db.models import Avg

action_pages = ActionGame.published.annotate(rating=Avg('reviews__rating'))
```

And then you can access it using `rating` attribute:

```py
action_pages[0].rating
```

UPD:
In your template access the rating:

```
{% for action_game in action_games %}
    ...

    <b>{{ action_game.rating }}</b> <br>

    ...
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: now help me here, how to write it in the template? because its returning me the same value on every **Action Game** object. l tried this `{{ xx}}`

Comment: @Byansi update your question, please, including how you are using it in template

Comment: okay let me do it

Comment: l have dropped it

Comment: thanks it worked. can l ask you , how can l remove the word **none** on the none rated objects and l return nothing till when someone ** rate** the object

Comment: @Byansi you can use built-in template tag [default_if_none](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/templates/builtins/#default-if-none)

Comment: Really thanks, you can help too on my next question